# Moodle - Sending notifications to Students

Tags: moodle

I am new to Moodle and I want to send email notification to students when the users are enrolled to a new course. When a new topic is added under the course, then also the students should be notified.

When the students completes the task or assignment, the notification is sent to the course creator. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK enrollment emails are only possible for Self enrollment (go to youradmin/admin/settings.php?section=enrolsettingsself and tick the checkbox on the bottom.)

No easy way for manual enrolment, though. Which is totally pity :(.

Here is tutorial for creating local hooks to allow this behavior https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=201499

D.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in `/enrol/manual/ajax.php` before `echo json_encode($outcome);`

```
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/moodlelib.php');
global $CFG;

$courselink = $CFG->wwwroot . "/course/view.php?id=" . $course->id;
$body = "Hi User<br/><br/>"."You have been enrolled to course"." ".$course->fullname."<`enter code here`br/><br/>"."Please login to start your course."." ".$courselink."<br/><br/>"."Thanks,"."<br/>Admin";
email_to_user($user,$USER,'Enrollment Notification','The text of the message',$body);
echo json_encode($outcome);
```